# interpreting Factorization Machines

Tags: machine-learning

I am using [fastFM](https://github.com/ibayer/fastFM) to run a factorization model.

Just wanted to know if there is an approach to interpreting the model?
How do I extract the Factorization Model equivalent of Variable Importance?